A limit problem in $p$-adic fields
I met a very concrete limit computation while dealing with some formulas in $p$-adic analysis.
Let $F$ be a finite extension over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with $p>2$ a prime. Let $E/F$ be a ramified quadratic extension. Let $\pi_E\in E^\times$ be a uniformizer of $E$, $\mathcal{O}_E$ (resp. $\mathcal{O}_F$) the integer ring of $E$ (resp. $F$). For the convenience of my computation the absolute value on $E$ is taken to be
$$|\pi_E|_E:=q^{-1/2},\quad \text{not}\quad |\pi_E|_E:=q^{-1}.$$
Now for any $\gamma\in (\mathcal{O}_E^\times-\mathcal{O}_F^\times)$, let
$$f(\gamma):=\max\{\left| \frac{\gamma-\overline{\gamma}}{\gamma-a}\right|_E:a\in \mathcal{O}_F^\times\}$$
where $\overline{\gamma}$ means the Galois conjugate of $\gamma$ over $F$.
My question is: when $(\mathcal{O}_E^\times-\mathcal{O}_F^\times)\ni \gamma\rightarrow 1$, does $f(\gamma)$ has a limit? I tried a very explicit method: $\gamma:=x+y\pi_E~(x,y\in F^\times)$ and write down
$$\left| \frac{\gamma-\overline{\gamma}}{\gamma-a}\right|_E=\left| \frac{y\pi_E}{(x-a)+y\pi_E}\right|_E.$$
But I did not find a clear way to explain what the limit is. (I guess it should be $1$, but I could not write down a precise proof of this.)
Any advise or hint is wellcome. Thanks in advance!

Because $E$ is ramified over $F$, $E \ne F$. If $|\gamma - \bar \gamma| > |\gamma - a|$ then Krasner's lemma implies that $E=F$. This means the limit is at most $1$.
Taking the computation you already did, we can always achieve the maximum when $a=x$,
$$\left| \frac{\gamma-\overline{\gamma}}{\gamma-a}\right|_E=\left| \frac{y\pi_E}{(x-a)+y\pi_E}\right|_E=\left| \frac{y\pi_E}{y\pi_E}\right|_E=1.$$
So the limit is $1$. More generally this will hold for any $\gamma \to b \in \mathcal{O}_F^\times$.
